# Redirect after file upload in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

My phonegap upload script works perfectly. After the upload you get a message "Please wait redirecting". I want to know how to add a redirection script so immediately after upload, it redirects to another page

```
    var deviceReady = false;

    /**
     * Take picture with camera
     */
    function takePicture() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(uri) {
                var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
                img.style.visibility = "visible";
                img.style.display = "block";
                img.src = uri;
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
            },
            { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
    };

    /**
     * Select picture from library
     */
    function selectPicture() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(uri) {
                var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
                img.style.visibility = "visible";
                img.style.display = "block";
                img.src = uri;
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
            },
            { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
    };

    /**
     * Upload current picture
     */
    function uploadPicture() {

        // Get URI of picture to upload
        var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
        var imageURI = img.src;
        if (!imageURI || (img.style.display == "none")) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Take picture or select picture from library first.";
            return;
        }

        // Verify server has been entered
        server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
        if (server) {

            // Specify transfer options
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+'.jpg';
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;




options.params = {
            filename: window.localStorage.setItem("key", options.fileName)

        }


            // Transfer picture to server
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://myphonegap.com/upload.php", function(r) {
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Please wait redirecting";             
            }, function(error) {
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;               
            }, options);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pictures uploaded to the server
     */
    function viewUploadedPictures() {

        // Get server URL
        server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
        if (server) {

            // Get HTML that lists all pictures on server using XHR 
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4){

                    // HTML is returned, which has pictures to display
                    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                        document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }

                    // If error
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = "Error retrieving pictures from server.";
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", server , true);
            xmlhttp.send();         
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Function called when page has finished loading.
     */
    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {deviceReady = true;}, false);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (!deviceReady) {
                alert("Error: PhoneGap did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly.");
            }
        },2000);
    }
```

Comment: What transition between pages do you use right now? jQuery and a Single-Page Application or do you just want to display another .html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the page transition at the end of the success function. E.g after This line:

```
document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Please wait redirecting";
```

Do:

```
window.location.href = "otherpage.html"
```

Or:

```
$('page1_div').hide();
$('page2_div').show();
```

Etc.

Comment: First you should have asked, what Framework he uses. Normaly you would use a single page application and make page transitions with jQuery. Then your answer isn't helpful